# PHP __toString() magic method doesn't return string (SOLUTION)

Tags: php, tostring

I have a class called FullName and I'm using toString() PHP magic method that should return a string but I'm receiving the Object directly:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Professional\Domain\ValueObjects;

use App\Professional\Domain\Exceptions\NameIsTooShortException;

final class FullName

{
    public $forename;

    public $surname;

    public function __construct(string $forename, string $surname)
    {
        $this->forename = $this->validateAndNormalize($forename);

        $this->surname = $this->validateAndNormalize($surname);
    }

    private function validateAndNormalize($name) : string
    {
        if (strlen($name) === 0) throw new NameIsTooShortException();

        return ucwords($name);
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->forename . ' ' . $this->surname;
    }
}
```

When I try this:

```
$name = new FullName($request->forename, $request->surname);
```

If I use:

echo $name;

the return is "Mike Gen"

but if I add the $name variable in array:

```
$returnValues = array(
    'id' => $professional->id(),
    'name' => $name,
    'message' => 'The professional has been updated'
);
```

Return is not the expected, I receive this:

{"id":"1","name":{"forename":"Mike","surname":"Gen"},"message":"The professional has been updated"}

FIXED thanks to @Nigel Ren, **the solution**:

```
$returnValues = array(
    'id' => $professional->id(),
    'name' => (string) $name,
    'message' => 'The professional has been updated'
);
```

Comment: `new FullName` created a new object of class FullName, why would `__toString` ever be called???  Try `echo $name;` then it will call `__toString`.

Comment: I don't see any usage of `__toString` here, do you use `echo $name`?

Comment: Works as expected: https://3v4l.org/pPH4W

Comment: If I try echo $name it return a string but if I add the $name variable to an array: $returnValues = array(
          'id' => $professional->id(),
          'name' => $name,
          'message' => 'The professional has been updated'
        ); its not added as string

Comment: It will add an object to the array - if you need the string then cast as using `'name' => (string)$name`

Answer (score 1):

`__toString` method is used when you want to get **string representation** of object, either **implicitly** when calling `echo $object` for example, or **explicitly**, when casting object to string or concatenating it with another string. In your code

```
$name = new FullName($request->forename, $request->surname);
```

you create a new `FullName` object and put it into `$name` variable.

To see how `__toString` works you need to cast object to string, for example:

```
echo $name;
// or
$str = 'The object as string is: ' . $name;
echo $str;
```

Also note, that `var_dump` or `print_r` **do not** cast object to string.

Here's a [simple fiddle](https://3v4l.org/ibVcC).

Going further:

```
{"id":"1","name":{"forename":"Mike","surname":"Gen"},"message":"The professional has been updated"}
```

is a **json**. `json_encode` **does not** use casting to string.

You either cast to string **explicitly**:

```
$returnValues = array(
    'id' => $professional->id(),
    'name' => (string)$name,
    'message' => 'The professional has been updated'
);
```

Or implement [`JsonSerializable`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php):

```
final class FullName implements JsonSerializable
{
    public function jsonSerialize() 
    {
        return $this->forename . ' ' . $this->surname;
    }
```

After that, encoding to json will work as expected without explicit casting to string - fiddle [here](https://3v4l.org/3OPa3).